# Can't edit an event in S Planner (Samsung Galaxy SII)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, calendar

I have an ancient repeating event in local calendar.

Some time ago I had a phone repair and then restored events via Kies. Now I need to edit the event and can't do this because `S Planner` shows it like meeting invitation. There is no "Edit" option, just "Copy", "Delete" and "Share Via".

Is there any way to convert event from meeting invitation back to a normal event without re-creating it? Do you know some "hacking" application which can modify events in an unrestricted way like "SMS Edit" does it for SMS?

The phone is GT-I9100
Android 4.1.2
Firmware I9100XXLS8